# Need to change my code to generate Correct JSON from Java Object - Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have following result for the query `select * from student where courseName = 'Science';`

Results:

```
student_id | name   | points | course_name   | course_id |
+----------+--------+--------+---------------+-----------+
       1107| Matt   |   3000 |     Science  |    10     |
|      1108| Charley|  12348 |     Science  |    20     |

2 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

StudentsDetails.java:

```
@Entity(name = "com.StudentDetails")
public class StudentDetails extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

  private long studentId;
  private String name;
  private long points;
  private String courseName;
  private long courseId;

  public StudentDetails(long studentId, String name, long points, String courseName, long courseId) {
    this.studentId = studentId;
    this.name = name;
    this.points = points;
    this.courseName = courseName;
    this.courseId = courseId;
  }

  public long getStudentId() {
    return studentId;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public long getPoints() {
    return points;
  }

  public String getCourseName() {
    return courseName;
  }

  public long getCourseId() {
    return courseId;
  }
}
```

I want to generate a JSON string like :

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "students": [
        {
          "name": 'Matt',
          "points": 3000,
          "course_name": 'Science',
          "course_id": 10
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "324",
      "students": [
        {
          "name": 'Charley',
          "points": 12348,
          "course_name": Science,
          "course_id": 20
        }
      ]
    },   
    {
      "id": "898",
      "error": {
        "error_code": "500",
        "error_message": "Details not found"
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

Part of Implementation code currently looks like :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < studentDetails.size(); i++) {
      Details details = new Details();
      details.setName(studentDetails.get(i).getName());
      details.setPoints(studentDetails.get(i).getPoints());
      details.setCourseName(studentDetails.get(i).getCourseName());
      details.setCourseId(studentDetails.get(i).getCourseId());
      Listdetails.add(details);
      item.setListDetails(Listdetails);
   }
   response = mapper.writeValueAsString(item);
```

Above code prints the wrong JSON like :

```
{"items":[{"id":"1107","details":[{"name": "Matt","points":3000,"course_name":"Science,"course_id":10},{"name":"Charley","points":12348,"course_name":"Science","course_id":20}]}]}
```

instead of

```
{"items":[{"id":"1107","details":[{"name": "Matt","points":3000,"course_name":"Science,"course_id":10}]},{"id":"1108","details":[{"name":"Charley","points":12348,"course_name":"Science","course_id":20}]}
```

Please help me to write a good implementation code to generate the correct JSON.
(Note : It is not the real code - just a sample of the real code)

In short : I want to read the entries from the database table and make it as:

```
items array -> [
            0th index : student_id, other related details (1107,['Matt',3000,'Science',10]
            1st index : student_id, other related details(1108,['Charley',12348,'Science',20]
              ]
```

Comment: what is Details? a course? what is item?

Comment: why does a student have a course name?

Comment: The JSON is not performant since creating a list were only one student is in it, is not needed.

The JSON that get's generated is basically pretty good. You can of course add an ID before the student.
Either change your `Details`Object to also hold an ID or create an `Wrapper` POJO to hold those values.

Also think about Maurice doubts and questions. They seem dubious.

Comment: it seems that your table `student` is not normalized

Comment: it is not the real code, but works same as that. I just simply gave course name instead of my real code

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in your Json you should use double quotes (") in order the json to be valid.
Finally you should use Jackson 2.x library. This is a cleaner way to manipulate and produce json formatted data. Below you can find a possible implementation:

```
-----------------------------------com.example.Error.java------------------- 

package com.example;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"error_code",
"error_message"
})
public class Error {

@JsonProperty("error_code")
public String errorCode;
@JsonProperty("error_message")
public String errorMessage;

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java----------------

package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"items"
})
public class Example {

@JsonProperty("items")
public List<Item> items = null;

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Item.java--------------------
package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"id",
"students",
"error"
})
public class Item {

@JsonProperty("id")
public String id;
@JsonProperty("students")
public List<Student> students = null;
@JsonProperty("error")
public Error error;

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Student.java-----------------

package com.example;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"name",
"points",
"course_name",
"course_id"
})
public class Student {

@JsonProperty("name")
public String name;
@JsonProperty("points")
public Integer points;
@JsonProperty("course_name")
public String courseName;
@JsonProperty("course_id")
public Integer courseId;

}
```

Comment: The issue is something like : I have to get an array  -> 0th index will be 2 entries - id, an array of other details .